# Access PHP Protected Classes

Tags: php

I am using a 3rd party script which returns data in a protected class.

> InstagramAPI\FollowerResponse Object ( [followers:protected] => Array ( [0] => InstagramAPI\User Object ( [username:protected] => touchmyjace [has_anonymous_profile_picture:protected] => [is_favorite:protected] => [profile_pic_url:protected] => http://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14583326_277270599333297_6673967741591879680_a.jpg [full_name:protected] => harlee [pk:protected] => 1474468910 [is_verified:protected] => [is_private:protected] => [coeff_weight:protected] => 0

I dont want to change the class because it is 3rd party and didnt work well when I tried. I need a way to access/convert these so I can access them.

Thanks

Comment: Use the public methods available to access the properties. If you use an IDE (netbeans, phpstorm, etc) the editor will auto complete what's available so you don't have to dig around the source files yourself.

Comment: Check out the second answer in the duplicate involving the `ReflectionClass`. That should do what you want